# Could there be any difference between using "over" and "to" in the idiom "to cast one's mind back"?

Tags: meaning

Examples from [Longman](http://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/cast_1):

> 1 - Cast your mind back to your first day at school.
>
> 2 - He frowned, casting his mind back over the conversation.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: No.

Long(er) answer:

There may be some very subtle difference in the implied amount of time; to my ear, "to" seem to imply a single point in time, or perhaps a starting point, whereas "over" give me the image of floating over a memory, looking down from the top, and taking in a much longer period of time at once.

With that said, this is a *really* trivial difference unless you're writing a poem (or otherwise using poetic elements). No one would notice the difference.